# How can I use mqtt to connect hono to ditto?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, eclipse-ditto, ditto, hono

Is it possible to use mqtt to send data from a device (arduino in my case) to hono and then send these data to ditto via mqtt?
in my case I have arduino that send a value via mqtt to hono, but now i need the data to be received by ditto.

For the moment i have only arduino that sends data to hono via mqtt.

Comment: You can just subscribe to MQTT broker with that specific topic on ditto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Ditto can either consume messages directly from an MQTT broker using MQTT 3.1.1 or MQTT 5:

- https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/connectivity-protocol-bindings-mqtt.html
- https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/connectivity-protocol-bindings-mqtt5.html

Or, utilising Eclipse Hono as device connectivity layer, consume messages via Apache Kafka or AMQP 1.0 (which Hono uses for "northbound" applications ingesting telemetry data).
If you need Eclipse Hono, I suggest to have a look at the "Cloud 2 Edge" package in the Eclipse IoT Packages project which already automatically sets up and configures both Eclipse Hono and Eclipse Ditto to work with each other:

- https://www.eclipse.org/packages/packages/cloud2edge/

If you only need to send data via MQTT, I would suggest to use an MQTT broker (like Eclipse Mosquitto) as this simplifies the setup a lot.
If you have requirements towards supporting multiple IoT protocols or massive scalability requirements, Eclipse Hono is a good choice.

Comment: If I use just an MQTT broker and Ditto is it possible to do operation of Command and Control? I mean the digital twin interacts with the physical device.

Comment: Of course - those are just messages to the device.

Comment: another question, is it possible to receive data on ditto via mqtt and send this data via kafka to influxdb?